# Google+ api with dart chrome app - 403 Daily Limit

Tags: dart, google-plus, google-oauth, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use the [google_plus_v1_api](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_plus_v1_api) + [google_oauth2_client](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_client) within a chrome packaged app.

Everythin works fine when i am using only the oauth2 lib:

```dart
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(new chrome.TokenDetails(interactive:true))
.then((token){
       OAuth2 auth = new SimpleOAuth2(token);
       var request = new HttpRequest();
       request.onLoad.listen((d){print(request.response); 
       request.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me');
       auth.authenticate(request).then((request) => request.send());
});
```

But i can't make google+ lib works:

```dart
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(new chrome.TokenDetails(interactive:true))
.then((token){
       OAuth2 auth = new SimpleOAuth2(token);
       Plus plus = new Plus(auth); 
       plus.people.get('me').then((d)=>print(d));
});
```

Return this exception:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me 403 (Forbidden) 
>   Exception: APIRequestException: 403 Daily Limit for Unauthenticated
>   Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Am i missing something? How am i supposed to use google+ api lib?

Comment: I remember getting this when using an invalid API key. No key normally works, but not an invalid key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw your answer, but wanted to point out I had the same problem and solved it by setting the `makeAuthRequests` property of the `Plus` client to `true`:

```
final plusclient.Plus plus = new plusclient.Plus(auth)
    ..makeAuthRequests = true;
```

Seems like a more straightfoward solution, since the auth object already contains the token.  I would've expected `makeAuthRequests` to be automatically set to `true` when constructing a `Plus` client with an OAuth2 object, but apparently it's not (probably an oversight).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i figured out that this line was missing thanks to this [tutorial](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html) :

```dart
plus.oauth_token = auth.token.data;
```

My google_plus_v1_api query is now working.
Sorry for the inconvenience.